# If I were to run a motor slower, would the battery drain less?

Tags: voltage, batteries, motor, dc-motor, amperage

This might be a dumb question, but I'm using a 48 V, 18 Ah battery to run a 48 V, 1800 W brushless motor. I calculated a predicted 34.6 min runtime at full throttle, however, I need it to be able to run around an hour+.

If I were to lower the speed at which I drive with my throttle and motor controller, will it drain less to get me towards that desired time? If not I am able to swap over to a 36 V 1000 W motor and use a battery with higher amperage that runs at 36 V. Would this be a smarter move for endurance? I'm attempting to drive a one-person barebones go-kart on this motor (using sprockets for torque if needed).

Comment: Does the torque (that is required to be produced) reduce as you decrease speed?

Comment: TANSTAAFL: If you want the Kart to accelerate and reach a certain speed, changing gearing to operate the motor slower would not increase run time. Of course, is you don't mind the  kart accelerating and running more slowly, then, yes, you could run all day operating the motor slowly with an efficient controller.

Comment: _"I calculated a predicted 34.6min runtime at full throttle"_ - what was the calculated motor efficiency and cruising speed?

Comment: I calculate slightly less than 29 min at 1800 watts load, however most vehicles are not used at full load for extended periods of time.  If you haven’t quantified your drive cycle I would just say build it and see what happens - then explain the numbers you measure.

Answer (score 0):

Much also depends on the type of battery you are using. A lithium battery can provide its rated voltage and current up to about 90% of its rated capacity, but it's recommended to limit discharge to about 80%. Lifetime is greatly reduced over that amount, and running it flat can be dangerous and cause permanent damage.

A lead-acid battery will start at about 2.2 volts per cell (13.6 V for a 12 V battery), and will steadily drop to about 1.8 volts per cell (10.8 V for a 12 V battery) when depleted. It will also be damaged if run flat, but is more forgiving than lithium batteries. They also suffer from the [Peukert Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law), which lowers the effective capacity depending on how much current is supplied. Your 18 A-h battery needs to supply over 36 A for an 1800 W motor, which is about 2C. The Peukert effect results in an effective capacity of about 8 A-h, and a run time of about 0.22 hours, or about 15 minutes.

You can use my [EV Calculator](http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm) to factor in vehicle speed, weight, aerodynamic drag, and acceleration (or slope for steady speed).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your controller "lowers" the speed of your motor. Some motor control just changes the speed (and increases torque) thru gear shifting but it essentially draws the same power from the source. Another way is thru applying a limit resistor to lower the current to the motor but that resistor will dissipate the extra current, effectively not changing the total power drawn from the source.

To measure if motor speed affects the power drawn, just put an ammeter between the Battery and the whole circuit to see if the current changes when you adjust the motor speed.